# Kotlin Runtime errors on basic operators

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I am running a project on IntelliJ that has a mix of kotlin and Java; when I build the project I get a heap of errors which shouldnt occur. for example, the following code throws the error:

**Error:(129, 23) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: +=**

```
override fun startMessagingService(RPCOps: RPCOps?) {
    // Start up the embedded MQ server
    messageBroker?.apply {
        runOnStop += Runnable { messageBroker?.stop() }
        start()
        bridgeToNetworkMapService(networkMapService)
    }
}
```

Obviously these are just basic operations and shouldn't fail. When I click on the error message it doesn't show an error in the actual code file. Perhaps my configuration is wrong? If so; how to go about fixing it?

There are many other errors that throw on basic operations like the one above.

Comment: How is `runOnStop` defined?

Comment: We need more information on the `messageBroker` object.

Comment: also check whether your stdlib version and kotlin-gradle versions are the same... gave me weird errors once

Comment: This looks like a compile error not a runtime error.  Is the title incorrect or did you not post the runtime exception?

Comment: It's hard to answer you question because this peace of the code relates external 'references' It would be much easier to help you it you would prepare sample that any body can copy&paste&run inside own IDE.